# VBA Word trying to shade SELECTED cells in one table in word that are bold

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am used in Excel and am not very experienced with Word VBA. I don't know how to get at a selection from a word table. I have tried something like the below but I don't know how to specify the selection from the currently selected table.

```
Sub Fill_Bold()
    For Each Cell In Selection.Cells
        If Cell.Font.Bold = True Then
            Cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking about but I prepared the answer referring to the title of your question. Assumptions:

1. your selection is within any table
2. you want to search for any cell which is bold
3. fill it with red color.

Here is your code improved where required:

```
Sub Fill_Bold()
Dim myCell
For Each myCell In Selection.Tables(1).Range.Cells

    If myCell.Range.Font.Bold = True Then

        myCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed

    End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

**Important!** You can't use `cell variable` name as `cell` is an object in Word, in fact both `cell` and `cells` are object/collection.

Comment: Thank you very much KazJaw, this is almost what i am after and will reward the answer. Ideally i would like to have a selection of only some of the cells in a table and apply the effect but your answer is near enough. Thanks, Cam